# Implementing a cache within a Repository using HashMap question

Tags: java, caching, concurrenthashmap

*I got this question on an interview and I'm trying to learn from this.*

Assuming that this repository is used in a concurrent context with billions of messages in the database.

```
public class MessageRepository {
    public static final Map<String, Message> cache = new HashMap<>();
    
    public Message findMessageById(String id) {
        if(cache.containsKey(id)) {
            return cache.get(id);
        }
        Message p = loadMessageFromDb(id);
        cache.put(id, p);
        return p;
    }
    
    Message loadMessageFromDb(String id) {
        /* query DB and map row to a Message object */
    }
}
```

What are possible problems with this approach?

*One I can think of is `HashMap` not being a thread safe implementation of `Map`. Perhaps `ConcurrentHashMap` would be better for that.
I wasn't sure about any other of the possible answers which were:*

**1)** Class `MessageRepository` is `final` meaning it's immutable, so it can't have a modifiable cache.

*(AFAIK `HashMap` is mutable and it's composed into `MessageRepository` so this wouldn't be an issue).*

**2)** Field `cache` is `final` meaning that it's immutable, so it can't be modified by put.

*(`final` doesn't mean immutable so this wouldn't be an issue either)*

**3)** Field `cache` is `static` meaning that it will be reset every time an instance of `MessageRepository` will be built.

*(`cache` will be shared by all instances of `MessageRepository` so it shouldn't be a problem)*

**4)** `HashMap` is synchronized, performances may be better without synchronization.

*(I think `SynchronizedHashMap` is the synced implementation)*

**5)** `HashMap` does not implement evict mechanism out of the box, it may cause memory problems.

*(What kind of problems?)*

Comment: There are some issues in every line which may need to be corrected or at least have some more thought and discussion. If you want to learn, it does not help if somebody is else is answering that for you, or, pointing your nose on it. Stackoverflow is for asking specific questions. In contrast, an ideal interview question leads to a broad discussion and further questions. If you are unsure about an aspect, e.g. 'static' or synchronized (meaning: thread safe!) look it up one by one and ask specific questions about each, if you cannot find a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with this cache. If `loadMessageFromDb()` is an expensive operation, then two threads can initiate duplicate calculations. This isn't alleviated even if you use `ConcurrentHashMap`. A proper implementation of a cache that avoid this would be:

```
public class MessageRepository {

  private static final Map<String, Future<Message>> CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public Message findMessageById(String id) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Future<Message> messageFuture = CACHE.get(id);
    if (null == messageFuture) {
      FutureTask<Message> ft = new FutureTask<>(() -> loadMessageFromDb(id));
      messageFuture = CACHE.putIfAbsent(id, ft);
      if (null == messageFuture) {
        messageFuture = ft;
        ft.run();
      }
    }
    return messageFuture.get();
  }
}
```

(Taken directly from JCIP By Brian Goetz et. al.)

In the cache above, when a thread starts a computation, it puts the `Future` into the cache and then patiently waits till the computation finishes. Any thread that comes in with the same id sees that a computation is already ongoing and will again wait on the same future. If two threads call exactly at the same time, `putIfAbsent` ensures that only one thread is able to initiate the computation.

Java does not have any `SynchronizedHashMap` class. You should use `ConcurrentHashMap`. You can do `Collections.synchronisedMap(new HashMap<>())` but it has really bad performance.

A problem with the above cache is that it does not evict entries. Java provides `LinkedHashMap` that can help you create a LRU cache, but it is not synchronised. If you want both functionalities, you should try `Guava` cache.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if you found it useful. This way, anyone who comes across the question knows the answer to it.